# Ios Build error - Couldn't write Gemfile.lock - Expo React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I'm getting an error while trying build and pa or ios app

This is what happens in the terminal
I select Yes I have an apple id, but even if I say no I get this error

This happened after I fill type my email and password -

```
Authenticating to Apple Developer Portal...
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that 
you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/dist/lib/vendor/Gemfile.lock
Authenticated with Apple Developer Portal successfully!
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
You have no team associated with your Apple account, cannot proceed.
(Do you have a paid Apple Developer account?)
Error: You have no team associated with your Apple account, cannot proceed.
(Do you have a paid Apple Developer account?)
    at _chooseTeam (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/appleApi/authenticate.ts:147:11)
    at authenticate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/appleApi/authenticate.ts:55:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Context.ensureAppleCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/context.ts:81:24)
    at IOSBuilder.bestEffortAppleCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:97:14)
    at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:153:5)
    at IOSBuilder.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:62:7)
    at IOSBuilder.command (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:39:7)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:79:7)
```

I've searched but have not found a solution.

I would appreciate it if someone would give me a solution.

Do I need to submit to AppStore to view the app

Do I need an apple developer account to build
I have an account.

I was able to build for android without any questions regarding a play store account which I don't have.

Why is it that ios need so much info.

I would appreciate it if someone would give me a solution.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create app that can be submitted to the App Store you need to have paid apple account. Only thing that you can do without that account is to:

- create simulator build `expo build:ios -t simulator`
- eject and build debug version in xcode

> I was able to build for android without any questions regarding a play store account which I don't have.

`build:ios` command generates release build that can be uploaded to App Store, to do that expo needs to generate Distribution Certificate, Provisioning Profile and Push Notification Key. To generate all of those credentials Apple account is required. This is not expo limitation, this process is enforced by Apple.